# Check excel versions (format) using vba

Tags: excel, phpexcel, aspose-cells, vba

I want my VBA code to execute only if the file format is xls. Is this correct?
I'm doing this:

```
#If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = xlExcel5 Then
  //my code
Else
  //my code
#End if
```

I tested using Excel 2010 (xlsm file) and it worked fine.
I already used PHPExcel library and this is why I chose the xlExcel5, because It's similar to the excel5 I had to choose if I wanted to work with the old excel versions (2003 or lower) while programming in Php.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat` will not give you the Excel Version. It will only give you the file format as you already mentioned. If you want to check the Excel Version on a particular pc then you have to use `If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then` What exatcly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In fact what I want is really the file Format. I wanna know if I check it for xlExcel5, I can garantee it's a 2007 or lower version. Or can I have a xlExcel5 format generated in a 2010 excel?

Comment: BTW the value of `xlExcel5` is 39. You can check that by typing `?xlExcel5` in the immediate window. Similarly the value of `FileFormat (xlExcel8)` for `xls` is 56. For more on fileformats, see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: I was typing when you posted the previous comment. let me check your previous comment

Comment: The above link will answer your first question. For the 2nd, the answer is `It Depends` If you have the VBA convertor installed then yes you can have a `xlExcel5` format generated in a 2010 excel. If you do not have the convertor then the `xls` file will be saved without the VBA project if any. `xlExcel5` format is the `Excel 5.0/95 format`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Please add your suggestions as an answer - I'd upvote and agree with the approach)